# How can i run an uberJar comprised of cucumber/groovy tests and dependencies

Tags: gradle, jar, uberjar

here is what i am trying to accomplish:

Build an uberJar for the EndToEndFunctionalTests tests :

```
task uberJar(type: Jar,dependsOn:[':compileGroovy']) {
    zip64 true
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from configurations.runtime.asFileTree.files.collect {zipTree(it) }
    with jar

}
```

as a result, i get:

EndToEndFunctionalTests-develop.local.SNAPSHOT.jar

so what i am trying to do is to execute this as:

```
$ java -jar EndToEndFunctionalTests-develop.local.SNAPSHOT.jar
no main manifest attribute, in EndToEndFunctionalTests-develop.local.SNAPSHOT.jar
```

is there a way to fake a main() and include it in the MANIFEST, so this jar executes.

I was able to run cucumber tests from the command line via gradle using cucumber runner, but what i want is to be able to run the jar because:

1. I would be able to run this jar anywhere, since it has all the dependencies
2. I would cut short the running time for these tests, in staging and qa, as i would have to just make it once, and run it in various environment, in the Continuous Integration Pipeline

Comment: if there is a main, you can include it the manifest. What do you mean by "fake a main" ? What class do you need to execute when you run java -jar?

Comment: @RaGe these are cucumber/groovy tests so there IS no main() method. So if you jar xvf EndToEndFunctionalTests-develop.local.SNAPSHOT.jar you will get all the .class files along with ALL the dependencies

Comment: You can use a groovy script to launch the test, and package groovy into your jar, so you can launch the script as an executable. See here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/09/groovy-goodness-running-scripts-from.html

Comment: the source code files are all .java files, so i do:
jar cvf ExternalXApplicantSteps.jar ExternalXApplicantSteps.java
added manifest
adding: ExternalXApplicantSteps.java(in = 7067) (out= 1541)(deflated 78%) but when i run:

 
groovy jar:file:ExternalXApplicantSteps.jar'!'/ExternalXApplicantSteps.jar
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: Why aren't you using gradle to run cucumber tests from the command line?

Comment: sorry cant join chat from my network.

Answer (score 0):

```
src/main/groovy/Test.groovy

class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                 println 'dummy main'
}
```

and result:

```
java -jar Serenity-develop.local.SNAPSHOT.jar
dummy main
```

its is executable, but now i have to figure out if i can call cucumber runner from this class